# Finite abelian group A cyclic iff for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $|\{a\in A \mid a^n = 1\}| \leq n$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to prove that a finite group A is cyclic if and only if $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ , there are at most n elements in A with $a^n=1$.

Heres what I've come up with so far:

Suppose that A is cyclic. We know that $H=\{a\in A \mid a^n =1\}$ is a cyclic subgroup of A, thus is generated by an element of order n or less. Therefore H has n or fewer elements.

Now for the converse, what I feel inclined do is assume that A is not cyclic and then get that there must be more than n elements with $a^n=1$.

Any thoughts on how I might finish this one off are appreciated.

Comment: $H=\{a\in A: {\color{red}{ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}}}, a^n=1 \}$? And what is $m$?

Comment: Instead of $H$ I should have put $H_n$. The m was a typo I fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the FTFAG, $A$ is not cyclic only if it contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p\times \Bbb Z_p$, which implies there are $p^2-1\gt p$ elements of order $p$.